# Where can I find the default Object.cshtml Editor template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, scaffolding

I need to modify the default editor template for scaffolding but I havent found the Object.cshtml template, where can I find the default razor Object.cshtml Editor template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following blog post describes how to customize the editor templates: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

Basically you have to add a file named `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Object.cshtml` and put all the logic for displaying the object there.

Comment: I'm looking for the original template, so I can just modify what I need to change instead of writing it from start, anyway I guess I'll just use the aspx one and convert it to razor.

Comment: The "original" template is actually hard-coded in System.Web.Mvc.dll so there is no asxc or cshtml file that you could look at. Making those default templates more available is something on the list for MVC 4, though I can't promise anything.

Answer (score 6):

When @marcind says they're compiled in, the templates themselves are not embedded but are rather written in code. For example, `EditorFor` calls `TemplateFor` which may call `TextAreaExtensions.TextArea` or one of many other extensions which generate the code that is ultimately output. This may be because the we have the option of removing the default view engine and using something like [nhaml](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/).

The mapping between the template names and the function creating the resulting output can be seen in `System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers`. See also `System.Web.Mvc.Html.DefaultEditorTemplates`.

The closest thing that exists right now are the Webforms templates that exist in Mvc3Futures which are available on the [aspnet.codeplex.com website](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781). Within it exists an DefaultTemplates\EditorTemplates folder that contains the templates.

Here's the Object.ascx template:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<script runat="server">
    bool ShouldShow(ModelMetadata metadata) {
        return metadata.ShowForEdit
            && metadata.ModelType != typeof(System.Data.EntityState)
            && !metadata.IsComplexType
            && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata);
    }
</script>
<% if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) { %>
    <% if (Model == null) { %>
        <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText %>
    <% } else { %>
        <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText %>
    <% } %>
<% } else { %>    
    <% foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => ShouldShow(pm))) { %>
        <% if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) { %>
            <%= Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName) %>
        <% } else { %>
            <% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.Label(prop.PropertyName).ToHtmlString())) { %>
                <div class="editor-label"><%= Html.Label(prop.PropertyName) %></div>
            <% } %>
            <div class="editor-field"><%= Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName) %> <%= Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*") %></div>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```